# Universal Static Library iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, static-libraries

I've created 2 static libraries for my SDK. One which is for device (armv7, arm64) and one universal, which is for device and simulator (i386 + x86).

 - I want to use only one instead of two, but the sizes are 1.5mb and 2.9mb respectively.

Does Apple use only the active architectures of the SDK, thereby using only 1.5mb even if I give the 2.9mb SDK?

Answer (score 2):

It should only pull the object files out of the static library needed to build the executable. So, my guess would be the file size would remain unchanged.

You can test this. Build two .ipa files. One linked with the device lib and one linked to the universal lib. Compare the sizes of the two .ipa files.

Comment: I had done that. The size difference came out to be 60kb, while the original difference was 1.4mb. While 60kb seems insignificant now, it can bloat to a larger value when the SDK is bigger. One would want to know what that 60kb is :)

Comment: @Jeffrey. You are right, it does pull the right object files from the executable. But that 60kb hit is bugging me